# Android Studio ClassCastException: com.worklight.wlclient.WLPersistentCookieStore

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/configuring-a-native-android-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#insideNativeApp) to integrate `MFP 7.1 SDK` into a native android application.  The application is built using latest `Studio 1.5.1`.  The MFP android native API component is deployed on my development server.  For testing purposes, I set the Application Access on native API to "active, notifying" because I want to see the pop-up appear in Android app.  When I invoke `WLClient` connect call from `Java` code, I see the following `class cast exception`.  The application does not crash however I do not see the active notification dialog/pop-up.

```
02-05 01:57:07.010 2992-2992/com.ibm.test.myapplication I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-05 01:57:07.130 2992-3011/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/com.worklight.common.Logger: com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed once.
02-05 01:57:07.130 2992-3011/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/wl.request: WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://192.168.1.3:10080/MFPNativeApps/authorization/v1/clients/instance
02-05 01:57:07.130 2992-3011/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/WLClient: WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStarted in WLClient.java:1476 :: on activity started com.ibm.test.myapplication.MainActivity
02-05 01:57:07.130 2992-3011/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/WLClient: WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityResumed in WLClient.java:1465 :: on activity resumed com.ibm.test.myapplication.MainActivity . activity count = 1
02-05 01:57:07.130 2992-3013/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.worklight.wlclient.WLPersistentCookieStore cannot be cast to org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:93)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:295)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:165)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:413)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-05 01:57:07.140 2992-3012/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-05 01:57:07.150 2992-3011/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/wl.certManager: WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
02-05 01:57:07.200 2992-3013/com.ibm.test.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-05 01:57:07.220 2992-3013/com.ibm.test.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 01:57:07.220 2992-3013/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:57:07.220 2992-3013/com.ibm.test.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3fd8e60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Here's my application gradle file.  Note that I tried the tutorial recommended ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation pom 7.1.0.0 as well without any luck.  The gradle below uses 7.1.5.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories{
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibm.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.foundation:ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation:7.1.5@aar'
}
```

Finally, here's the MainActivity Java code:

```
package com.ibm.test.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient;
import com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLFailResponse;
import com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponse;
import com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponseListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WLResponseListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        WLClient.createInstance(this).connect(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onSuccess(WLResponse var1) {}
    public void onFailure(WLFailResponse var1) {}

}
```

Comment: I think I found the answer.  It was a silly mistake in gradle file.  I had to use the following loopj version: `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'`.  I will add some comments to the tutorial for someone who runs into this problem again.

Comment: Please also write this as an answer and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. It was a silly mistake in gradle file. I had to use the following loopj version: `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'`. I have added comments to the tutorial for someone who runs into this problem again.